# Add specific JRE to .Net Dockerfile

Tags: java, c#, .net, docker

I'm setting up a .net Docker image, with some .net code within it. The code, however, needs access to a very specific version of Java Runtime (`jre-7u9-windowsx64.exe`).

I don't know exactly where to start in adding this executable into my dotnet Dockerfile.

The current Dockerfile for dotnet

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build-env
WORKDIR /name

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "name.dll"]
```

I would just like to get the JRE added to the Dockerfile so it is installed or available when Docker spins up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the JRE forms part of your runtime environment, you're going to want to install it into your `# Build runtime image`.

Your ideal goal is to find the lowest common multiple, sufficient to run both ASP.NET and your .NET code and the JRE and your Java code.

#### Option #1: Find a (trusted) container image that runs both ASP.NET and JRE

Presumably, you've pursued this approach and been unsuccessful.

#### Option #1: Start from your currently working solution and add

I'm unfamiliar with `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet` but this may well continue to suffice as your baseline and it has the advantage that you know it will run your .NET app.

So, your process will be to determine what additionally -- if anything -- you'll need to install to be able to run `jre-7u9-windowsx64.exe`.

A hacky way to determine this would be to insert whatever the installer is for this binary (between lines 13-14). This will take the form `RUN` the jre-7u9-windowsx64.exe installer. Then, try to build your container and see what errors arise.

A more considered approach would be to identify whether you need to install additional packages to support `jre-7u9-windowx64.exe` and, if you do, you'll need to install those (using further `RUN ...`) commands beforehand.

#### Option #2: Start from a minimal baseline and add

Alternatively, you could start from a more foundational baseline. I assume the OS here is Windows rather than Linux. Presumably there's a minimal Windows container image?

Then you'd need to add whatever is needed to:

- Get ASP.NET and your .NET code working
- Get JRE and your Java code working

This would provide a more considered foundation for your image *but* at the cost of requiring you to solve two puzzles.

#### Option #3: Start from a working JRE image and add

Included for completeness but not-recommended in this case.